# LINQ for Javascript (JSON,Arrays, DOM)?

Tags: javascript, linq

i am looking for some input for how to use linq with javascript, there are number of implementations for javascript around.

anybody use any and which is the most compatible?

I was looking to be able to use linq against JSON and the DOM

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A LINQ-like library for JavaScript is [JSLINQ](http://www.codeplex.com/JSLINQ). It seems to have quite a full implementation.

Example from site:

```
var myList = [
        {FirstName:"Chris",LastName:"Pearson"},
        {FirstName:"Kate",LastName:"Johnson"},
        {FirstName:"Josh",LastName:"Sutherland"},
        {FirstName:"John",LastName:"Ronald"},
        {FirstName:"Steve",LastName:"Pinkerton"}
        ];

var exampleArray = JSLINQ(myList)
                   .Where(function(item){ return item.FirstName == "Chris"; })
                   .OrderBy(function(item) { return item.FirstName; })
                   .Select(function(item){ return item.FirstName; });
```

This should be fine for JSON - as JSON is basically just objects. The DOM, while workable, might be a bit more clunky; you'd probably be best using something else.

Comment: JSON is a data format. What you get when you parse JSON is ordinary JavaScript object(s). It makes more sense to talk of JSON as being basically a string.

Comment: I am aware of that - I was talking about manipulating the parsed JSON and then reserialising it, which seems the most natural way to me.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i found another here http://linqjs.codeplex.com/   it seems a little more complete with delegate support, anybody used it?

Comment: I've not used it before, but it seems just as good. :) I'm a bit confused about your statement regarding "complete with delegate support" - the first example on the site is C#, then the JS uses anonymous functions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry i wasn't clear... it mimics a delegate which in effect is an anonymous function /method....

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript libraries such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) have methods that work on enumerables and provide filtering, projecting, etc like LINQ does. For example, the [jQuery.grep()](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.grep) method works just like LINQ's Where() by filtering items according to the given (anonymous) function and  [jQuery.map()](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map) projects items like LINQ's Select().